# How to alternatively concatenate pytorch tensors?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Pytorch provides API to concatenate tensors, like cat, stack.
But does it provide any API to concatenate pytorch tensors **alternatively**?

For example，[image]

suppose `input1.shape = C*H*W`, `a1.shape = H\*W`, and `output.shape = (3C)*H*W`

This can be achieved using a loop, but I am wondering if any Pytorch API can do this

Comment: Where is a1 in your illustrative example?

Comment: a1 = the first line of input1.
Forgot to add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to do it with small example:

```
input1 = torch.full((3, 3), 1)
input2 = torch.full((3, 3), 2)
input3 = torch.full((3, 3), 3)

out = torch.concat((input1,input2, input3)).T.flatten()
torch.stack(torch.split(out, 3), dim=1).reshape(3,-1)

#output

tensor([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]])
```